# Deserialization of wrapped json property

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

what is the easiest way to deserialize a such json:

```
{
  "xx": {
    ...
   }
   "user": 
       {
        "name": "john"       
   }
}
```

to:

```
class User {
  String name;
}
```

using jackson?

Answer (score 0):

If Json is valid then you can simply use `http://json2csharp.com/` to get the desired result.

Comment: u can use `http://jsonutils.com/` also to get the final result. But your json is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
  json = {
           "xx": {
                   ...},
           "user":{
                    "name": "john"       
                   }
         }
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(json);
  String name = root.path("user").get("name").asText();
  user.setName(name);
```